# Table creation in stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I have created a stored procedure in oracle to create a back up table for an existing table. while executing the SP, i am getting error.

```
 
create or replace PROCEDURE proc_clear_table_for_automation_temp
IS
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
begin
    sql_stmt := 'create table transaction_method_' || SYSDATE || ' as (select * from transaction_method)';  
    execute immediate sql_stmt;  
END;
i have created above procedure but while executing it using
exec proc_clear_table_for_automation_temp;

i am getting following error

Error starting at line : 11 in command -
BEGIN proc_clear_table_for_automation_temp; END;
Error report -
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
ORA-06512: at "REL55.PROC_CLEAR_TABLE_FOR_AUTOMATION_TEMP", line 7
ORA-06512: at line 1
00922. 00000 -  "missing or invalid option"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Can someone help on this
```

Comment: If you change your procedure to do `dbms_output.put_line(sql_stmt);` before the `execute immediate`, and enable output in your client before calling the procedure (e.g. `set serveroutput on` in SQL\*Plus etc.), then you'll see exactly what it's trying to run. Often that makes it fairly obvious what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use explicite conversion of the `SYSDATE` to a string

e.g.

```
'create table transaction_method_' || to_char(SYSDATE,'yyyymmdd')
```

you avoid possible spaces that are not valid in table names.